# Kivy(framework): blank window after running code

Tags: python, oop, kivy

After running this code python idle gave me a blank window without any kivy widgets and python idle does not show any error.
what is the problem in this code?
[screen shot of blank window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81cpB.png)

---

### code:

```html
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class me(App):
     def __init__(self,b,g,l,t):
          super(me, self).__init__()
          self.b=Button(text='start')
          self.g=GridLayout(cols=4)
          self.l=Label(text='label')
          self.t=TextInput()
          self.g.add_widget(self.b)
          self.g.add_widget(self.t)
          self.g.add_widget(self.l)


m=me('b','g','l','t')

m.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Building the `App` should be done in a `build()` method of the `App`, and that method should return the root widget for the `App`. Like this:

```
class me(App):
     def __init__(self,b,g,l,t):
          super(me, self).__init__()
          self.b=Button(text='start')
          self.g=GridLayout(cols=4)
          self.l=Label(text='label')
          self.t=TextInput()
          self.g.add_widget(self.b)
          self.g.add_widget(self.t)
          self.g.add_widget(self.l)

    def build(self):
        return self.g
```